Why Pending Intent is not invoked in list inside widet?
I created widget in kotlin. In this widget i have list.
Every item in list is clickable and i want to by click open MainActivity with extras. But if I click on item nothing is happening.
Here is how i setOnClick in getViewAt function:
remoteViews.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.listitem_overlay, openMainActivity(departure))

and here is openMainActivityFunction
   private fun openMainActivity(departure: Departure): PendingIntent {
        val fillInIntent = Intent(context, MainActivity::class.java)

        fillInIntent.apply {
            `package` = context.packageName
            addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK)
        }


        fillInIntent.putExtra(TRIP_ID, departure.tid)
        fillInIntent.putExtra(OPERATOR_NAME, operator)
        fillInIntent.putExtra(STOP_FULLCODE, departure.stopFullcode)
        fillInIntent.putExtra(ACTION_OPEN_TRIP, ACTION_OPEN_TRIP)

        return  PendingIntent.getActivity(context,123, fillInIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)
    }

And here is code how i set remoteAdapter to list in widget
private fun setDepartures(
    fullcode: String,
    schedule: String,
    lines: String,
    appWidgetId: Int,
    views: RemoteViews,
    context: Context,
) {
    val intent = Intent(context.applicationContext, StopDepartureService::class.java)
    intent.putExtra(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, appWidgetId)
    intent.putExtra(PREF_PREFIX_KEY_OPERATOR, schedule)
    intent.putExtra(PREF_PREFIX_KEY_FULLCODE, fullcode)
    intent.putExtra(PREF_PREFIX_KEY_STOP_LINES, lines.trim().replace(" ", ","))
    intent.data = Uri.parse(intent.toUri(Intent.URI_INTENT_SCHEME))
    views.setRemoteAdapter(R.id.departureList, intent)
}

setDepartures is invoked in updateAppWidget which is invoked in for loop in onUpdate
